# Increment a value in Firebase Realtime Database (Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, redux

I'm trying increment a value by one on click. However, I'm getting an error message of:

> 'firebase' is not defined  no-undef.

Below is my code, am I using the correct syntax? I am using Redux.

Please let me know if I should provide more details.

```
import  database from '../firebase';

export const makeLikePost = (id) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        database.ref(`posts/${id}/like`)
        .push({
            like: firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(1)
        })
        .then(() => {
            dispatch(likePost(id))
        });
    }
}
```

[image]
Screenshot of Realtime Database

EDIT1 - firebase.js file:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to import firebase

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
```

Although you seem to be importing something at the top? Is this your own firebase database config exported? In that case try

```
    import  database from '../firebase';
    
    export const makeLikePost = (id) => {
        return (dispatch) => {
            database.ref(`posts/${id}/like`)
            .push({
//remove the "firebase."
                like: database.ServerValue.increment(1)
            })
            .then(() => {
                dispatch(likePost(id))
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but I get an error message: Cannot read property 'increment' of undefined

Comment: Hmm it has to be an import issue. Can we see the firebase file you import at the top?

Comment: Edited my original post, added  a screenshot of the firebase file.

Comment: I got it to work by using this instead of increment:

export const makeLikePost = (id) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        database.ref(`posts/${id}/like`)
        .transaction(function(value) {
            return (value || 0) + 1;
          })
        .then(() => {
            dispatch(likePost(id))
        });
    }
}